# Improve Bus Speed/Throughput of a Qemu Guest (with KVM disabled)

Tags: qemu

I have an IBM POWER with 96 cores and 512GB. Host operating system is Debian ppc64. Qemu-5.2 (qemu-system-x86_64) is running a Debian x86 guest. No KVM because they're different architectures.

Debian x86 guest only achevie 1.1 GB/s when running "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M". I need it at least 3GB/s.

The same issue with disk I/O. I delivered a ramdrive to the guest and  "dd if=/dev/vda of=/dev/null bs=1M" was only 200MB/s.

Thats one of the several commad lines I tried:

qemu-system-x86_64
-bios OVMF.fd -machine q35  -smp cpus=16 -m 32G -mem-prealloc
-boot d -cdrom grml64-small_2020.06.iso
-drive if=none,id=ram1,file=/dev/ram0,aio=threads,format=raw -device virtio-blk,drive=ram1
-serial telnet::4441,server
-vga none -nographic

PS: I notice the guest cpu clock is always only 510MHZ. I wonder if higher clock could turn bus "wider"...

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm curious: do you get similar I/O speed if you run a [PPC64 debian](https://wiki.debian.org/PPC64) with qemu?  This should at least tell you whether it's `qemu`'s x86_64 emulation, or just `qemu` in general.  I expect a ppc64 debian chroot would have host native performance.

Comment: other not an answer: Running qemu-x86_64 (qemu user emulation rather than system emulation) in an LXC container would keep the native kernel handle its side of /dev. I just don't know if the combination power -> x86_64 exists. I also know that some system calls aren't always correctly translated (eg: commands to add firewall rules might fail), but for classical processes, this might be an alternate option.

Comment: Not an answer #1: I think so, anyhow I'll try that.
Not an answer #2: I don't know about LXC, but I'll try it.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not really about LXC but QEMU "user mode" that allows to execute foreign architecture elf binaries. Those binaries could be present on the main installation using multi-arch settings (eg: `dpkg --add-architecture amd64` + `apt-get update` + `apt-get install hello:amd64` ) but sooner or later conflicts happen especially for dev packages. So having them present in a separate installation is easier.